# Functional test and nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, testing

I have a Story resource nested in a User resource. 
How do I fix this generate functional test?

```
  test "should create story" do
    assert_difference('Story.count') do
      post :create, story: @story.attributes
    end

    assert_redirected_to story_path(assigns(:story))
  end
```

DGM solution still have the story_url problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide the user id it is nested in:

```
post :create, story: @story.attributes, user_id: @user.id
```

The path may be something like,

```
user_story_path(@user.id, assigns(:story))
```

Comment: This is what I get: StoriesControllerTest
     test_should_create_story                                            ERROR
        undefined method `story_url' for #<StoriesController:0x007fa6094df470>
        STDERR:
        Exception `NoMethodError' at /Users/Simone/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/actionpack-3.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/polymorphic_routes.rb:127:in `polymorphic_url' [...]

Comment: Ok it was my fault. redirect_to in #create still use only @story and not [@user, @story]