# How to test nested routes in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, functional-testing

I have route:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :records do
      resources :grades
    end
  end
```

How do I functional test them?

I can make `get` test for `record` right:

```
 test "should get index" do
    get :index, user_id: @user
    assert_response :success
    assert_not_nil assigns(:records)
  end
```

How do I test `post`?

```
assert_difference('Record.count') do
  post :create, record: { comment: @record.comment, device: @record.device, status: @record.status }
end

# I will get error
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:record=>{:comment=>"MyText",
:device=>"MyString", :status=>"pending"}, :controller=>"records", :action=>"create"}
```

Comment: That seems fine? Then you could do something like `assert_redirected_to record_path(assigns(:record))`

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8021693/functional-test-and-nested-resource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html for information on functional/controller tests in rails.

A good example from the guide:

```
test "should create record" do
  assert_difference('Record.count') do
    post :create, record: { comment: 'Some comment', device: 'Some device', status: 'Some status'}, user_id: @user.id
  end

  assert_redirected_to user_record_path(@user.id, assigns(:record))
end
```